# How to use datetime in Julia?

Tags: datetime, julia

I am using Julia 0.3.0 on Windows 8.1

These examples came from the Datetime manual at
https://github.com/quinnj/Datetime.jl/wiki/Datetime-Manual

I tried this:

```
julia> using datetime
Warning: requiring "datetime" did not define a corresponding module.

julia> date(2013,7,1)
ERROR: date not defined

julia> today()
ERROR: today not defined

julia> dt = date(2013,7,1)
ERROR: date not defined

julia> dt = datetime(2012,6,30,18,59,50,0,CST)
ERROR: datetime not defined

julia> datetime(2013,7,1,12,0,0,0,UTC)
ERROR: datetime not defined
```

How do I create a datetime object?
I understand that DateTime will be deprecated and that Dates will be the new datetime module.
I added that package but I can't find any intructions on how to use it.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hUBiydGl6E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line should be `using Datetime`, after installing the Datetime package with `Pkg.add("Datetime")`.

```
julia> using Datetime

julia> date(2013,7,1)
2013-07-01

julia> today()
2014-09-01

julia> dt = date(2013,7,1)
2013-07-01

julia> dt = datetime(2012,6,30,18,59,50,0,CST)
2012-06-30T18:59:50 CDT

julia> datetime(2013,7,1,12,0,0,0,UTC)
2013-07-01T12:00:00 UTC
```

Until Julia 0.4, you should stick with this.

Comment: At the Julia command line that worked but in Julia Studio I got this
julia> Pkg.add("Datetime")
INFO: Nothing to be done.

julia> 


julia> using Datetime
Warning: requiring "Datetime" did not define a corresponding module.


julia> dt = datetime(2012,6,30,18,59,50,0,CST)
ErrorException("datetime not defined")

Comment: I did uninstall/reinstall of Julia Studio.  Then Pkg.add("Datetime") I get WARNING: Datetime had build errors. Pkg.rm("Datetime")  produces INFO: No packages to install, update or remove.  Is there a way to add an earlier, perhaps stable, version of Datetime?

Comment: @BarryAndersen You say you are using Julia v0.3. However, JuliaStudio comes packaged with Julia v0.2. If you're running v0.3 from the terminal but v0.2 from JuliaStudio, packages you download for one won't be available for the other. Alternatively, it is possible you are installing a Datetime package designed for v0.3 into the JuliaStudio environment. Just some musings. By the way, I looked into JuliaStudio, but found the [Sublime-IJulia](https://github.com/quinnj/Sublime-IJulia) approach to ultimately be much more useful.

Comment: Sorry @BarryAndersen that sounds cryptic, I'm not sure how that could happen. If possible I'd move away from using Julia Studio, it is no longer well supported by the 3rd-party company that created it - it is not supported by the Julia developers.

Comment: OK so I quit using JuliaStudio. Now at the Julia prompt I type  Pkg.add("Datetime") I get INFO: Nothing to be done. And when I type using Datetime and I get Warning: requiring "Datetime" did not define a corresponding module. Then when I type  dt =  datetime(2000,1,1,12,0,0)   I get ERROR: pkg not defined

Answer (score 1):

An update just in case somebody still read this (first result on duckduckgo):
julia Datetime is [deprecated](https://github.com/quinnj/Datetime.jl) since from julia 0.4-dev there's the package Dates that got merged.

So, the right way nowadays (julia 0.5, 0.6) is to use Base.Dates like in

> Base.Dates.today()

or in

> import Base.Dates; now()

Answer (score 1):

An update using Julia 1.5.1 to solve it:

- Open the julia interpreter with the command:

```sh
/Applications/Julia-1.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia
```

*NOTE*: replace the full path with the path you have julia installed at (or even better add it to the global PATH variable)

- Inside the julia interpreter run this commands:

```
julia> import Pkg
julia> Pkg.add("Dates")
```

And that's it !!

Now you should be able to run julia programs with a code like:

```
using Dates

println(DateTime(2020))
```

More info about the Dates julia API can be found at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Uninstall/Reinstall Julia to get rid of Datetime package. run Pkg.add("Dates"), user manual here docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/dates

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hUBiydGl6E